# Can't reset variable in redux store

Tags: react-native, react-redux

At the moment I'm still a newcomer to Redux.

App has a page with categories, clicking on one of which opens a new window with a list of available entries in it.
This window has a position in its state from which you can begin querying the data.

The problem is that when an app starts the window, performs an action that clears the state. But for some reason, the variable with the position does not change.

(I know, I can just move this position to the component variable, but as a novice, I want to understand the problem)

Action for download items:

```
getLatestDataInCategory: (category, currNum) => {
return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({type: actionTypes.DATA_IN_CATEGORY_LOADING_ENABLED})
    fetch('http://************/api/rf_api/get_rf_list.php?category='+category+'&startFrom='+currNum)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((res) => {
        dispatch({type: actionTypes.DATA_IN_CATEGORY_LOADING_DISABLED})
        dispatch({type: actionTypes.DATA_IN_CATEGORY_ADD_DATA, payload: {data: res.results}})
        dispatch({type: actionTypes.DATA_IN_CATEGORY_ADD_NUM})
    }).catch(error => {
        dispatch({type: actionTypes.DATA_IN_CATEGORY_ERROR, payload: {error: error}})
        dispatch({type: actionTypes.DATA_IN_CATEGORY_LOADING_DISABLED})
        console.log(error)
        })

 }
}
```

Action to clear data:

```
clearData: () => {
return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({type: actionTypes.DATA_IN_CATEGORY_CLEAR})
 }
}
```

Reducers:

```
export const reducersDataInCategory = (state = initialStateDataInCategory, action) => {
   const {type, payload} = action

   switch(type) {
        case actionTypes.DATA_IN_CATEGORY_LOADING_ENABLED:
            return{...state,
            isLoading: true}
            break
        case actionTypes.DATA_IN_CATEGORY_LOADING_DISABLED:
            return{...state,
            isLoading: false}
            break
        case actionTypes.DATA_IN_CATEGORY_ADD_DATA:
            return{...state,
            data: [...state.data, ...payload.data],
            error: null}
            break
        case actionTypes.DATA_IN_CATEGORY_ERROR:
            return{...state,
            error: payload.error}
            break
        case actionTypes.DATA_IN_CATEGORY_ADD_NUM:
            return{...state,
            currNum: state.currNum + 30}
            break
        case actionTypes.DATA_IN_CATEGORY_CLEAR:
            return{...state,
            currNum: 0,
            data: []}
            break
        default:
            return state
            break
   }
}
```

in Component:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.clearData()
    const categoryId = this.props.navigation.getParam('categoryId', 1)
    this.props.getLatestFormulasInCategory(categoryId, this.props.currNum)
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what the 'variable with the position' is, which part of the state are you referring to?

Comment: currNum. This is variable with the number of rows I need to get from the server